# Open file indentation unexpected

Tags: python, file, indentation

I am a newcomer to developing in python I had a good search to see if I could answer my question prior to posting this, but my searches came up blank.

I am opening a file with random indentation and I want to search through it to find a specific line and write it in another file later on. For this, I am using:

```
with open("test.txt", "r+") as in_file:
buf = in_file.read().strip()
in_file.close()
out_file = open("output.txt", "w+")
for line in buf:
    if line.startswith("specific-line"):
        newline == line + "-found!"
        out_file.append(newline)
    out_file.close()
```

While my code loads and reads the file without any issues, the thing I'm struggling with is how to ignore the indentation in my "test.txt" file.

For example:

I might have.

```
ignore this line
ignore this line
specific-line one
specific-line two
ignore this line
    specific-line three
specific-line four
        specific-line five
ignore this line
ignore this line
```

in my file.

My code as it stands will only find the lines that start with '*specific-line*' and have '*one*', '*two*' and '*four*' in them.

What do I need to do to my code to change it, so that I also get the lines with '*specific-line*' plus '*three*' and '*five*' in also, but while ignoring any other lines (marked as - '*ignore this line*') that I don't want.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks! =]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems, related to the way you read in the `in_file`. The line:

```
buf = in_file.read().strip()
```

will only `strip` whitespace from the start and end of *the whole file*, then:

```
for line in buf:
```

is actually iterating over *characters*. Also, you don't need to `close` if you use `with`.

Instead, try:

```
with open("test.txt") as in_file, open("output.txt", "w+") as out_file:
    for line in map(str.strip, in_file):
        if line.startswith(...):
            ...
```

---

Additionally, as `Brionius` points out in the comment, you're comparing (`==`) instead of assigning (`=`) to `newline`, which will cause a `NameError`.

Comment: Also they're using "==" where they mean to use "=".  Add that to your answer and +1.